# Sort JavaScript array of Objects by two properties and given order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this JavaScript array of Objects:

```
data = [
    {'deviation': 57.41, 'provider': "This", 'measure': "median"},
    {'deviation': 49.02, 'provider': "All", 'measure': "median"},
    {'deviation': 199.67, 'provider': "This", 'measure': "third_quartile"},
    {'deviation': 152.31, 'provider': "All", 'measure': "third_quartile"},
    {'deviation': 41.48, 'provider': "This", 'measure': "first_quartile"},
    {'deviation': -1.07, 'provider': "All", 'measure': "first_quartile"}
]
```

and I would like to sort it both by 'provider' (the three "This" before the three "All") and by 'measure' (first quartile, median, third quartile), so the resulting array will look like:

```
data = [
    {'deviation': 41.48, 'provider': "This", 'measure': "first_quartile"},
    {'deviation': 57.41, 'provider': "This", 'measure': "median"},
    {'deviation': 199.67, 'provider': "This", 'measure': "third_quartile"},
    {'deviation': -1.07, 'provider': "All", 'measure': "first_quartile"}
    {'deviation': 49.02, 'provider': "All", 'measure': "median"},
    {'deviation': 152.31, 'provider': "All", 'measure': "third_quartile"},       
]
```

I have written a function as an argument to `.sort()`, and it does return the array sorted by 'provider', but then when I feed it into the same function with `measure` as an argument (thankfully, first_quartile, median, third_quartile are already alphabetically sorted the way I want them) - the sorting gets broken. How can I go about doing it?

**EDIT**
The functions I have been using:

```
var compare_prv = function(a,b) {
  if (a.provider < b.provider){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

var compare_meas = function(a,b) {
  if (a.measure < b.measure){
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have forgotten to include the elusive function you mentioned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: Okay and how do you call compare_prv and compare_meas? Why are you returning zero?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are doing:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    //sort by provider
});

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    //sort by measure
});
```

But what you want to do is:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    //sort by provider, but if they are equal, sort by measure
});
```

So something like

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.provider === b.provider) {
        return a.measure.localeCompare(b.measure);
    }
    return b.provider.localeCompare(a.provider);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the sorting criteria with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

> For a set of strings with a defined order, you could use an object for getting the wanted order.
>
> ```
> {
>     first_quartile: 1,
>     median: 2,
>     third_quartile: 3
> }
> ```
>
> This lets you sort some item, if not in the order list ssort to start with default zero or to bottom with a huge value like `Infinity`.
>
> In this case the pattern looks like
>
> ```
> (order[a.measure] || 0) - (order[a.measure] || 0)                // to top
> (order[a.measure] || Infinify ) - (order[a.measure] || Infinity) // to bottom
> ```

```js
var array = [{ deviation: 57.41, provider: "This", measure: "median" }, { deviation: 49.02, provider: "All", measure: "median" }, { deviation: 199.67, provider: "This", measure: "third_quartile" }, { deviation: 152.31, provider: "All", measure: "third_quartile" }, { deviation: 41.48, provider: "This", measure: "first_quartile" }, { deviation: -1.07, provider: "All", measure: "first_quartile" }],
   order = { first_quartile: 1, median: 2, third_quartile: 3 };

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.provider.localeCompare(a.provider) || order[a.measure] - order[b.measure];
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```